# How to prevent span symbol be viewed in fixed navbar

Tags: html, css

Need your help on a HTML CSS issue.
I want use a fixed Navbar on top of the page. And a "main" layout following.
however, when I use a Span symbol arrow up with "position absolute".
the symbol can be viewed from the Navbar when I scroll page down.
Is anyway it can be hidden while I scroll page down?
thank you,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .main {
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: 40px;
      top: 40px;
      height: 1500px;
      /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<body>


  <div class="main">
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <span style="position:absolute; color:green; margin-left: 2px; margin-top: 1px;">   &#x25B2;</span>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: invalid HTML . you have elements outside of the body tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the addtribute `z-index` to the class `navbar` and your `span`. Therefore the arrow will be placed under the navbar on scrolling.

I also placed your navbar inside the `body` tag.

```css
.navbar{
  z-index: 9999;
}

.yourspan{
  position:absolute; 
  color:green; 
  margin-left: 2px; 
  margin-top: 1px; 
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    .navbar {
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #333;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .navbar a {
      float: left;
      display: block;
      color: #f2f2f2;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 17px;
    }
    
    .main {
      padding: 16px;
      margin-top: 40px;
      top: 40px;
      height: 1500px;
      /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
    }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
<div class="navbar" style="z-index: 99;">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

  <div class="main">
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <span class="yourspan">   &#x25B2;</span>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
    <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @rendolph, good to know the Z-index. Quite interested ! it solved my issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Just make it disappear with JavaScript when you scroll:

```js
tri = document.querySelector('.yourspan');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    const scrollHeight = window.pageYOffset;
    if (scrollHeight > 20) {
        tri.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
        tri.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.main {
    padding: 16px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    top: 40px;
    height: 1500px;
    /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
span {
    position:absolute;
    color:green; 
    margin-left: 2px; 
    margin-top: 1px;"
}
```

```html
    <div class="navbar" style="z-index: 99;">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
      
        <div class="main">
          <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
          <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
          <span class="yourspan">   &#x25B2;</span>
          <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
          <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you @sedki for your answer. and I prefer use the static way like Z-index.